# Prevent certain activities from starting without being started from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

The main activity that starts when my app launches is shown with a bunch of menu items but access to some of the activities that are launched by some of the menu items require a username and password. After the user enters their credentials correctly, they have access to those activities. They can also use the back button and return to the main activity where the menu is located and I don't require them to re-enter their credentials again, as long as they remain within the app.

If however they hit the Back button while in the main activity, I terminate the app with finish();

The problem I am seeing is that if the user presses and holds the Home button, the list of apps is shown and if they tap on my app, they could end up being taken to one of the "secured" activities that requires a username and password. This can happen if they were using one of those activities and hit the Home button.

The solution I came up with is just to use a global variable that indicates that they are signed in and clear this when they hit the Back button from within the main activity.

But I need to check for this flag in the onResume of every activity to see whether they are signed in or not and if not, I do a finish() in the onResume preventing them from accessing the activity.

Is there a better way of doing this? Perhaps a way of terminating all the activities that are spawned when the user enters a "secured" activity? Or better yet, terminate all activities within my app? As it stands, I have a lot of activities and repeating the code in my onResume seems kind of senseless.

Comment: And why is that behaviour a problem? If the user is already logged-in, why do you want to prevent him to switch between different apps and then come back to your app in a secured activity?

Comment: Anyway, I usually do that kind of control tasks using noHistory in the AndroidManifest when needed and extending onResume in related activities (the only way to check if the user logged-out from another activity).

Comment: Can noHistory be set on an activity basis or is that a setting for then entire app, meaning the entire app has no history?

Comment: If you set that in some activities of your AndroidManifest, it means that only those activities have no history. Very useful for Splash and Login activities.